# Russian characters are shown as ??? in java

Tags: java, json, spring, utf-8, utf-16

I have a controller which has to return a JSON string with a Russian name, but all I get in response is ????? (invalid characters).

```
@Controller
public class ManifestController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/manifest.json","/manifest"}, method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})

    public String getManifestJson(
            HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        Employee e= new Employee ();
        e.setName("Мегафон Игры"); 

        return JsonUtil.jsonStringify(e);  //it converts object to json using JsonObjectMapper


    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how at all `Employee e` is ever used in your code. Also you seem to know your issue according to your tags

Comment: JsonUtil Please show this class as well

Comment: How do you inspect the response?

Comment: Most likely, whatever you're using to display the response is incapable to handle Russian.

Comment: Most likely the code above is not the problem. So the problem could be: (1) the web server adding invalid headers to the response (unlikely), (2) your Java compiler using the wrong encoding for the source code  (3) the REST service client, (4) the way you inspect the result or the result is displayed.

Comment: even if i try to do System.out.println("Мегафон Игры") inside my controller it shows ??? in eclipse console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me to set the encoding in the response header:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried that on my machine and it's work

```
  User e = new User();
  e.setFirstName("Мегафон Игры");
  ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
  String json;
  json = ow.writeValueAsString(e);
  return json;
```

that what i recived :

```
{
"id": 0,
"creationDate": null,
"username": null,
"firstName": "Мегафон Игры",
"lastName": null,
"email": null,
"updateDate": null,
"active": 0
}
```

Comment: I guess you are not using a web controller. Normally it works but in case of a spring MVC controller even System.out.println("Мегафон Игры") it shows ??? In console. I tried adding uriEncoder =utf-8" in server.xml file of tomcat too